# Can I rewrite for-of loop to Promise.all?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a piece of code that loops through the array of users and filters them out based on a particular property. After that, I push user ids to a separate array.

Example:

```js
// User's props:
// user: { id, name, subscriptions, isSubscribed: () => {} }

const userIds = []

for (const user of users) {
  const isSubscribed = await user.isSubscribed(category)

  if (isSubscribed) {
    userIds.push(user.id)
  }
}
```

**I am wondering if such a sequential code could be rewritten to a parallel (with `Promise.all` for example)?**

Answer (score 2):

After the `isSubscribed` call, chain on the `user.id` if they're subscribed, otherwise `undefined` (or some other value distinguishable from an actual ID) so that that's what an individual Promise resolves to. Then filter the array for only values that are IDs.

```
const userIds = (await Promise.all(
  users.map(
    user => user.isSubscribed(category)
      .then(isSubscribed => isSubscribed ? user.id : undefined)
  )
))
  .filter(userId => userId !== undefined);
```